# nested for loop to lapply for list of matrices - non identical output

Tags: r, for-loop, nested, apply, lapply

I made a calculation for a nested loop, then I tried to transform it to lapply but it doesn't show the same result, do you know why is it? This is my code:

```
#list
l <- list()
l[[1]] <- matrix(c(4, 3, 20, 10), ncol=2)
l[[2]] <- matrix(c(3, 3, 40, 12), ncol=2)
l[[3]] <- matrix(c(2, 3, 60, 10), ncol=2)
#loop
##index
s <- 1:length(l)
#for loop
zzz <- list()
for (i in s){
zzz[[i]] <- apply(X = l[[i]], MARGIN = 1, 
                FUN = function(x) spDistsN1(l[[i]], x, longlat = T))
zzz
}
#lapply loop
yyy <- lapply(s, function(x){
apply(X = l[[i]], MARGIN = 1, 
    FUN = function(x) spDistsN1(l[[i]], x, longlat = T))
})
```

And they output aren't identical, why?

```
identical(zzz,yyy)
[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can change the code  to

```
library(sp)
yyy <- lapply(s, function(i) apply(l[[i]], 1, FUN= function(x) 
             spDistsN1(l[[i]], x, longlat = TRUE)))
identical(zzz, yyy)
#[1] TRUE
```

---

In the OP's code, the anonymous function call used in both function is `x`, so within the `spDistsN1`, the `x` was coming from the whole `matrix` instead of the row